How to add point on local OpenStreetMap server through API?
I am trying this code to create point in my own server OSM but getting response 404 not found any help PLZ…
 string url = "http://192.168.43.177:8080/api/0.6/node/create";

        // Construct the XML payload
        string xmlData = $@"
            <osm>
                <node lat=""33.642782"" lon=""73.077733"" version=""1"" changeset=""1"">
                    <tag k=""key1"" v=""value1""/>
                    <tag k=""key2"" v=""value2""/>
                </node>
            </osm>";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Create the HTTP content with XML payload
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(xmlData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

            // Make the POST request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

I am trying this code to create point in my own server OSM but getting response 404 not found any help PLZ…

Check the log file(s) of your server.
